# Vue check in nested v-for if a record doesn't exist

Tags: vue.js

I am trying to build a table where rows are items (first v-for), columns are locations (second v-for), cells are item_locations (third -v-for).

If for a certain location the item is present (hence an item_location object) I want to print yes, else I want to print No.

```
<div v-for="item in items" :key="item.id>
 {{item.name}}
  <div v-for="location in locations" :key="location.id">
    <div v-for="item_location in location.item_locations" :key="item_location.id">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

By adding this in the third loop:

```
<p v-if="item_location.item_id == item.id">Yes</p>
```

I it correctly prints yes for combination of item/location for which there is an item_location.

What I am unable to do is to print No only for the combinations of item/location for which an item_location object does not exist. To further clarify, item_locations is a joining table.

Comment: You should use `computed` property to prefilter what data you put in your template, template is for displaying information, not for you to do logic on it. Take all the calculation, logic down to `script` part

Comment: For what I want to achieve this is not really doable with a filter in computed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this way:

```
<div v-for="item in items" :key="item.id>
 {{item.name}}
  <div v-for="location in locations" :key="location.id">
    <div>{{filterLocation(item, location)}}</div>
  </div>
</div>



filterLocation: function(item, location) {
  let value = item.item_locations.filter(item_location => {
  return item_location.location_id == location.id;
   });
   var that = this;
   that.item_location_exists = value.length;
},
```

And in template I can do a conditional as item_location_exists equals to 0 or 1.

Answer (score 0):

A little confused on what your asking but Im going to suggest this

Your nested `v-for` must use the property declared from its parent like so

```
<div class="table-cell" v-for="location in locations" :key="location.id">
      <div v-for="item_location in location.item_locations" :key="item_location.id">
            <div v-if="item_location.location_id == location.id ">Yes</div>
            <div v-else>No</div>
      </div>
</div>
```

so the nested `v-for` would be `location.item_locations` and if your only checking for one condition you can just do a `v-else`.

Comment: If I do location.item_locations then in the v-if I need to use item_location.item_id == item.id. Which prints Yes on the correct combinations of item/location. The problem is when I use the v-else, as it prints No for each not corrensponding location. But what I want to achieve is that if for a certain location there is not an item_location for that item then print No.

Comment: @Catmal, well theres multiple ways you could that. I am not sure what your data looks like but you could do something like `<div v-else-if="!item_location">No</div>` or use a computed property to loop through, or pass your property to a method that returns a value dependent on whatever condition, like `<div>{{filterLocation(item_location)}}</div>`

Comment: <div v-else-if="!item_location">No</div> does not work as for every combination of item and location there are some item_locations, but with wrong location_id. Hence that solution doesn't print any "No". v-else prints several No for each item location with wrong location_id. So yes I need to use a filter like if item.item_locations.where(location_id: location.id).length == 0. I just don't know the syntax for Vue.